# Linq Nhibernate left join

Tags: linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

A Theft has an **action** property

This is the query i'm trying to get NHibernate.Linq to produce:

```
SELECT * FROM `thefts`
LEFT JOIN memberThefts
ON thefts.id = memberThefts.theftId AND memberThefts.memberId = 1
```

I want to get a list of all the thefts where action.memberId == some number or just null if it doesn't find a row, simple as a query yet it's been giving me a nightmare all day!

```
        thefts = session.Query<Theft>()
            .Fetch(x => x.action)
            .Where(x => x.action.memberId == member.id)
            .ToList();
```

This executes the following SQL:

```
select theft0_.id                 as id9_0_,
       memberthef1_.memberId      as memberId7_1_,
       theft0_.name               as name9_0_,
       theft0_.chance             as chance9_0_,
       memberthef1_.theftId       as theftId7_1_,
       memberthef1_.availableTime as availabl3_7_1_
from   thefts theft0_
       left outer join memberThefts memberthef1_
         on theft0_.id = memberthef1_.theftId,
       memberThefts memberthef2_
where  theft0_.id = memberthef2_.theftId
       and memberthef2_.memberId =1 /* ?p0 */
```

The theft class:

```
    public class Theft
    {
        public virtual byte id { get; set; }
        public virtual string name { get; set; }
        public virtual byte rank { get; set; }
        public virtual byte chance { get; set; }
        public virtual MemberTheft action { get; set; }
...
```

And it's mapping:

```
public TheftMap()
{
    Table("thefts");
    Id(x => x.id);
    Map(x => x.name);
    Map(x => x.id);
    Map(x => x.chance);
    References(x => x.action)
        .Nullable()
        .PropertyRef(x => x.theftId)
        .Column("id");
}
```

Any solution will do HQL, QueryOver etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be done using the LINQ provider, but you can do it with QueryOver. Something along the lines of:

```
MemberTheft memberAlias = null;
var result = Session.QueryOver<Theft>()
                    .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => x.action, () => memberAlias)
                    .Where(() => memberAlias.memberId == member.id);
```

Edit: Updated Query.

Comment: I'm getting: The best overloaded method match for 'NHibernate.IQueryOver<Assassinators.Entities.Theft,Assassinators.Entities.MemberTheft>.Where(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Assassinators.Entities.MemberTheft,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Juddling I just updated the query, tested it and it's working. If it still doesn't work can you please update your question with your mappings/models so I can use that.

Comment: Ahh, I think* you still need to do `.Fetch(x => x.action).Eager`, I would need to setup a bunch of test data, don't have time, its 2-30am need to go sleep.