# NHibernate left join with linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, join, nhibernate

I need to change join in linq which is using NHibernate into left outer join.
My code look like this

```
IQueryable<DimServicePoint> spq =
                            from sp in session.Query<DimServicePoint>()
                            join spm in session.Query<DimServicepointMeter>() on sp.ServicePointKey equals spm.ServicePointKey into gj
                            from subsp in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where (sp.ServicePointID == servicePointID && sp.DimAccount.AccountKey != 0 && sp.StartDayID <= currentDateId && sp.EndDayID >= currentDateId)
                            select sp;
```

Now my requirement is join DimServicepointMeter with left join in this query.
Equivalent SQL query is :

```
select * from dw.dim_servicepoint sp
left join dw.dim_servicepoint_meter spm on sp.servicepointkey = spm.servicepointkey
where sp.servicepointid = @ServicePointID  and sp.accountkey != 0
and sp.startdayid <= @currentDateId  and sp.enddayid >= @currentDateId
```

I have not work much in NHibenate or linq so don't have much idea how to do left join in NHibernate or linq.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15590126/1162077

Answer (score 1):

Arbitrary left join are not currently (v4.1) supported in [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate). They translate to a LINQ [`GroupJoin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin(v=vs.110).aspx) which throws `NotImplementedException` when used with [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate).

As written in the [answer](/a/15590126/1162077) linked by [David](/questions/42410867/nhibernate-left-join-with-linq#comment71973154_42410867), you may use [queryover](/questions/tagged/queryover) instead. Plain [hql](/questions/tagged/hql) may do too (using theta style joins).

You may instead map your meters on your service points. It would looks like (without your `DimAccount` property):

```
public class DimServicePoint
{
    public virtual int ServicePointID { get; set; }
    public virtual int StartDayID { get; set; }
    public virtual int EndDayID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ServicePointKey { get; set; }
    public virtual ISet<DimServicePointMeter> ServicePointMeters { get; set; }
}

public class DimServicePointMeter
{
    public virtual int ServicePointMeterID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ServicePointKey { get; set; }
}
```

Mapped with:

```
<class name="DimServicePoint">
    <id name="ServicePointID">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="StartDayID" />
    <property name="EndDayID" />
    <property name="ServicePointKey" />

    <set name="ServicePointMeters" inverse="true" batch-size="20">
        <key column="ServicePointKey" property-ref="ServicePointKey" />
        <one-to-many class="DimServicePointMeter" />
    </set>
</class>
<class name="DimServicePointMeter">
    <id name="ServicePointMeterID">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="ServicePointKey" />
</class>
```

And then you could get your data with:

```
var spq = session.Query<DimServicePoint>()
    .Where(sp => sp.ServicePointID == servicePointID && sp.DimAccount.AccountKey != 0 &&
        sp.StartDayID <= currentDateId && sp.EndDayID >= currentDateId);
```

Accessing `.ServicePointMeters` on the query results would trigger a lazy-load of meters collections for at most 20 collection of the loaded service points. This is due to `batch-size` attribute in my proposed mappings. Without it (and without a globally configured `batch-size`), it would trigger the lazy-load of only one collection at a time, potentially leading to n+1 performance issues.

If you want to eagerly load them instead, just add the fetch:

```
var spq = session.Query<DimServicePoint>()
    .Where(sp => sp.ServicePointID == servicePointID && sp.DimAccount.AccountKey != 0 &&
        sp.StartDayID <= currentDateId && sp.EndDayID >= currentDateId)
    .FetchMany(sp => sp.ServicePointMeters);
```

The resulting query will use a left-join.

*Notes:

I personally avoid the LINQ sql-like syntax, I favor usage of LINQ extension methods as illustrated in my answer. I find them much more readable.

I favor lazy loading over eager loading with NHibernate, since it can batch load lazy loads. It tends to simplify the code while maintaining good performances, as I have explained [here](/a/36070727/1178314).*